# Isn't my book's solution about quadratic equations wrong?

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, roots, quadratics

**Problem:**

If the ratio of the two roots of the equation $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$ is equal to the ratio of the two roots of $a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2=0$, show that $\dfrac{(b_1)^2}{(b_2)^2}=\dfrac{a_1c_1}{a_2c_2}$.

**My book's solution:**

Let the roots of the equations $a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1=0$ and $a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2=0$ are $\alpha$ & $\beta$ and $\gamma$ & $\delta$ respectively. Now, according to the question,

$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{\gamma}{\delta}$$

$$\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{\gamma+\delta}{\gamma-\delta}$$

$$\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha-\beta}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\gamma+\delta}{\gamma-\delta}\right)^2$$

$$\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2}{(\gamma+\delta)^2}=\frac{(\alpha-\beta)^2}{(\gamma-\delta)^2}$$

$$\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2}{(\gamma+\delta)^2}=\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta}{(\gamma+\delta)^2-4\gamma\delta}$$

$$\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2}{(\gamma+\delta)^2}=\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2-((\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta)}{(\gamma+\delta)^2-((\gamma+\delta)^2-4\gamma\delta)}\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2}{(\gamma+\delta)^2}=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma\delta}$$

$$\frac{\frac{b_1^2}{a_1^2}}{\frac{b_2^2}{a_2^2}}=\frac{\frac{c_1}{a_1}}{\frac{c_2}{a_2}}$$

$$\frac{{b_1}^2}{{b_2}^2}=\frac{a_1c_1}{a_2c_2}(\text{showed})$$

**Questions:**

1. Isn't $(1)$ wrong? $4\alpha\beta\neq((\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta)$ and $4\gamma\delta\neq((\gamma+\delta)^2-4\gamma\delta)$. So, isn't $(1)$ wrong?
2. If $(1)$ is wrong, could you please provide me with an alternative correct solution to the problem?

Comment: Why do you think (1) is wrong?

Comment: You are correct, that $4 \alpha \beta \neq ((\alpha+\beta)^2 - 4 \alpha \beta)$. However, note that what is happening in that step isn't actually substitution of one of these for the other : it's just using the fact that if $\frac{a}{c} = \frac {b}{d}$ then both fractions are also equal to $\frac{a-b}{c-d}$ (provided $c \neq d$). The previous line contains a statement of the form $\frac ab = \frac cd$, and $(1)$ just uses the fact to get another identity from where everything follows.

Comment: I am personally more curious as to how they got from line 1 to line 2.

Comment: @Arthur That's covered under the "proportion rules" section, it often appears in high school Indian math textbooks. For a rough idea, see [here](https://www.toppr.com/guides/quantitative-aptitude/ratios-and-proportions/componendo-dividendo/), it's called the componendo-dividendo rule. Having said that, the case where some denominators in the computation can be zero were ignored.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon If it's a rule that's learned specifically, then that's fine. It's not a rule I'm familiar with from my curriculum, so personally I would've expected to see a few intermediate steps.

Comment: @Arthur I agree, that is a fair point.

Comment: A (IMO) simpler argument would be that $$\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2}{\alpha \beta} = \frac \alpha \beta + 2 + \frac \beta \alpha = \frac \gamma \delta + 2 + \frac \delta \gamma = \frac{(\gamma+\delta)^2}{\gamma \delta}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement $(1)$ is correct. Your statement, $4\alpha\beta\ne(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta\;$ and $\;4γδ≠(γ+δ)^2−4γδ$ is also correct.

[**Hint:**](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/)
$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{r}{s}\implies \frac{p}{q}=\frac{p-r}{q-s}$$

Comment: (You also need $q\not=s$.)